# How to collect different type of object (from one class template) in one container?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to do a thing like following code in C++:

I hope to collect all objects (created from class template 's') in to one container, say std::vector. I can achieve it through the way shown in the code here.

My problem is, if I want to pass arguments of specific type 'T' in class f or through a unified api, or get 'T' from one api. How to achieve that?

Thank you very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class f

{
public:
    f() {}
    virtual ~f() {}

    virtual void p() { std::cout << " class f\n";}
};

template<typename T>
class s : public f
{
public:
    s(T x) { m = x; }
    ~s() {}

    void p() { std::cout << " -> " << x << "\n"; }                                                                                                            
private:
    T m;
};

int main()
{
    int aa = 1;
    float bb = 5.9;
    std::string cc = "abc";

    s<decltype(aa)>* A = new s<decltype(aa)>(aa);
    s<decltype(bb)>* B = new s<decltype(bb)>(bb);
    s<decltype(cc)>* C = new s<decltype(cc)>(cc);

    std::vector<f*> vv;
    vv.push_back(A);
    vv.push_back(B);
    vv.push_back(C);

    for(auto a : vv) {
        a->p();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `f` has no knowledge about `T` or `s`. It can only send virtual functions through to the part that does.

Comment: All your classes s<...> are different classes seen by your compiler, so you can't hope generalize anything in your class f that would work for any s<...>.